# CURL - no url set

Tags: url, curl

```
$param = 'get.php';
$url = 'http://mysite.org/'. $param;
$__post = 'option=1&option2=225';
```

mysite.org/get.php - exists for 100%, when I open them in browser everything works.

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $__post);
$result = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
print_r($result); // show 404 o_O
```

I test it using sniffer and CURL pass URL :

```
http://mysite.org
```

not

```
http://mysite.org/get.php
```

when I do somethink like that :

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL,'http://mysite.org/get.php');
```

everything works fine... so... please help me :D What I do wrong, certainly it is a small error but I don't see where he is :/

Comment: It looks like it should work as-is. I'm assuming you changed the URL for this question, so is it possible there's an invalid character in the real one? (Spaces and non-ASCII characters typically need to be escaped.)

Comment: Yes I changed but it's really easy and looks like that, those I wrote here http://mysite.org and http://mysite.org/get.php  that's all.  Btw. sorry but my english it's not fluently. $param can have value : get.php / set.php.  Post fields should look : option=[0-9] &option2=[0-255].

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove this (`$param = 'get.php';`):

```
$param = 'get.php';
$url = 'URL'. $param;
$__post = 'option=1&option2=225';
```